# How does $\frac{(2n)!}{(2(n+1))!}$ become $\frac{1}{2(n+1)(2n+1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Searching for the radius of convergence for:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{3x^n}{(2n)!}$$
leads me to the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(2(n+1))!}.$$
How to simplify:
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(2(n+1))!}?$$
WolframAlpha gives:
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(2(n+1))!}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{4n^2+6n+2},$$
but I don't see how to get it.

So, the radius of convergence is equals to $R=+\infty$, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definition of the factorial, then

$$(2(n+1))!=(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)2n!$$

Therefore

$$\frac {(2n)!}{(2(n+1))!}=\frac {(2n)!}{2(n+1)(2n+1)(2n)!}=\frac 1{2(n+1)(2n+1)}$$

Comment: That is: (2n+2)!=1∙2∙∙∙(2n-2)(2n-1)2n(2n+1)(2n+2), is that correct? (Is it possible to use dollar signs for formulas in comments here?)

Comment: @misha.physics Yes to both questions - $\LaTeX$ is also supported in comments. Essentially, the key to these kinds of problems is to note that for factors like $n!$ and $(n+a)!$ where $a>0$, then $(n+a)!$ will always "contain" an $n!$ because $$\begin{align*}(n+a)! & =(n+a)(n+a-1)\ldots(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots2\cdot 1\\ & =(n+a)(n+a-1)\ldots(n+1)n!\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks! (Just for my experiment, $(2n)!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdot\cdot(2n-2)(2n-1)2n$.)